# Add Review option with Trunk based approach in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, trunk

Our project is decided to use trunk based strategy for our GIT repository management. Due to some reason we decided to deviate slightly from the trunk based way. Instead of using original 'master' branch we created another branch (say 'develop' branch) and consider it as trunk/master on which all developers commits on daily basis. Now I want to implement review facility for each commit being done by developer to our single branch(That is 'develop'), same as when we merge to master. Is there a way to achieve this ? Any idea will be highly appreciated. BTW we are using GitLab

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting your trunk/master branch as a protected branch? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#configuring-protected-branches

Comment: Protected branch will just restrict the branch and will not provide a review facility. I found a way to achieve review with help of Fork, where all developers are asked to create fork project and raise merge request to my original project